# Creating a new packet type with a few extra fields than the Packet in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I want to create a new packet type with a few extra fields than the Packet, preferably inherited from the Packet type. What is the best approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.msg` file with:

```
packet MyPacketType {
  int myField;
}
```